# Get subset of dataframe (python) based on requested column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following problem with a `dataframe` in python:

I have a `dataframe` with an ID column (which is not the index) and other columns.
Now I want to write a code that gives back a new dataframe with all rows that have the same value in columnx, as the requested item ID. It should also contain all columns of the dataframe df.

```py
def subset(itemID):

 columnxValue = df[df['ID'] == itemID]['columnx']
 subset = df[df['columnx'] == columnxValue]

 return subset
```

If I do it like this I always get the Error "Can only compare identically-labeled Series Objects

I changed the question to be more clear.

Comment: the explanation/pseudocode aren't totally clear to me. it would help if you could include a small sample dataframe and use that dataframe to explain which values you're trying to get based on what conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) as follows:

```
def subset(itemID):
    columnValueRequest = df.loc[df['ID'] == itemID, 'columnx'].iloc[0]
    subset1 = df[df['columnx'] == columnValueRequest]
    return subset1
```

As you want to get a value, instead of a Series for the variable `columnValueRequest`, you have to further use `.iloc[0]` to get the (first) value.

Comment: This gives back the columnx for the requestet itemID. But what I need is a dataframe with all of the rows, that have the same value in columnx, as the requested itemID

Comment: I always get the error that columnx is not defined. If I replace it with df['columnx'] It gives back all the rows columnx entries with the error that none are in the [columns]

Comment: @Python101   Enclose `columnx` by a pair of single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?
You give the `ItemID` as an argument to the `subset` function. Then it checks if the `ItemID` corresponds to the value in the `ID` column. It returns the value from `columnx` from the row where `ItemID` is equal to the value in the `ID` column.

```
def subset(itemID):
 columnValueRequest = df[df['ID'] == itemID][columnx]
 subset = df[df[columnx] == columnValueRequest]
 return subset
```

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks! This already helped But I always get the error "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects...